# What are finite horizon look-ahead policies in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, terminology, papers

I was reading the paper [How to Combine Tree-Search Methods in Reinforcement Learning](https://www.aaai.org/ojs/index.php/AAAI/article/view/4227) published in AAAI Conference 2019. It starts with the sentence

> Finite-horizon lookahead policies are abundantly used in Reinforcement Learning and demonstrate impressive empirical success.

What is meant by "finite horizon look-ahead"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this paper](http://adp.princeton.edu/Papers/Powell_ADP_2ndEdition_Chapter%206.pdf) a look ahead policy is a policy that will make decisions based on some 'horizon'. Here horizon means some time steps into the future, and so a finite horizon is simply a finite amount of time steps into the future. For example, as we are typically concerned with maximising returns in RL, a 10-step look ahead policy would choose an action at time $t$ that maximises the (expected) rewards at time $t+1, ... t+10$.

Comment: Arent all policies finite horizon lookahead policies as per bellman equations where the discount factor determine how far to look ahead?

Comment: No, for instance you can get some bandit algorithms that assume an infinite horizon. Gittins Index is an example.